# Google maps shows gray box

Tags: javascript, css, api, google-maps, maps

Working on a client site here: http://mcveighcreative.com/biofab/

I'm thinking it has something to do with the css, because on a quick refresh I can see that the tiles do load their images. Can't seem to figure it out.

I have combed through most of the questions and have implemented this in the header

```
#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;max-height: none;background:none!important}
```

Comment: did you set the google-maps api key ??

Comment: I tried that earlier and it made no difference. Plus it's only a warning in the console. That said, i should probably put it in soon

Comment: i was having the same problem bedore and without api key the map can not be shown in the G-maps include script try to have something like this 
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="YOUR_KEY"&libraries=places&callback=initMap' async defer></script>

Comment: Gave that a try now, still no good...

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36405299/4539433

Turns out that google maps doesn't like overflow: auto. Weird.

Had to resort to this in the header

```
<style>#gmap_canvas * {overflow: visible}</style>
```